# Automatically read xml into Datagridview onClick of TabControl

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

I have a winforms application that has one tabcontrol with 2 pages.

On both pages I have data that is displayed in a datagridview called TaskTable. The data is displayed from TaskDataSet which is bound to an XML file.

However, at the moment the only way of displaying the data is to click the Read XML button so when the either of the pages are first clicked the datagridview is empty which I don't like.

When the either of the pages are clicked I want the datagridview to automatically fill.

Any ideas how to do this:

Here is my code for the Read XML button if that helps:

```
private void ReadXmlButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // event handler to display saved tasks.
    {

        if (TaskTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(); // checkbox column = 'column'

            {
                column.HeaderText = "Complete";
                column.Name = "Complete";
                column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
                column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
                column.ThreeState = false;
                column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
                column.CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                column.CellTemplate.Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }

            TaskTable.Columns.Insert(0, column); // Column of checkboxes.

            TaskDataSet.Clear(); // Clears dataset
            TaskDataSet.ReadXml(fileURL);
            TaskTable.DataSource = TaskDataSet;
            TaskTable.DataMember = "Task";
            TaskTable.Columns[5].Visible = false; // hides numeric priority - only used for sorting
        }
        else
        {
            TaskDataSet.Clear(); // Clears dataset
            TaskDataSet.ReadXml(fileURL); // reads xml to retrieve any additional tasks that have been added to the XML file.                      
            TaskTable.DataSource = TaskDataSet;
            TaskTable.DataMember = "Task";
            TaskTable.Columns[5].Visible = false; // hides numeric priority - only used for sorting
        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Fill the data in form constructor? Some more context would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick google search shows that the TabControl raises a number of events - the following probably being the most appropriate:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected.aspx

hook up to that event and load your xml.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I made a slight mistake in my question. I have one tabControl not 2. What I want is events to be triggered based on which page of the tabcontrol is clicked. I'm guessing its a similar problem though!